# CSS "onclick" pseudo class is not working

Tags: jquery, css, html

This code is taken from http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/ with some modifications.

My purpose is to show modal form and close it when user click [x] button at the corner, or automatically close after 10 seconds.

The only problem is the form cannot close when i click [x] button. What's wrong in the code below?

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
           Hi, this is modal form.
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#openModal').fadeOut('slow'); }, 10000); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
.modalDialog:target {        
    opacity:0;
}

.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 28%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;    
    z-index: 99999;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call either fadeOut/close method in the on click event handler of close button.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#openModal .close').click(function(){
        $('#openModal').fadeOut('slow'); 
    }); 
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pRPJx/)

Answer (score 0):

This a working sample, save the code below as a .HTML file and use it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.modalDialog {
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in 0s;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
bottom: 0;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 99999;
}

.modalDialog:target {
opacity: 1;
pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #999999) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px;
position: relative;
width: 400px;
}

.close {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #606061;
border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000000;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
}

.close:hover {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00D9FF;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#openModal">Click this Link to open up a Model</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<a class="close" title="Close" href="#close">X</a>
<h2>Modal Box</h2>
<p>This is a sample modal ...ing the powers of CSS3.</p>
<p>You could do a lot of t...egister form for users.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First `add Id to you close button link`

```
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close" id="closeBtn">X</a>
```

Now In Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#closeBtn').on('click' , function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
        $('#openModal').fadeOut('slow'); }, 10000); 
      });
</script>
```